# Differentiation of a function wrt different variables

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Suppose a function
"*f* (*xy*)", then does it equate to "*f* ' (*xy*) . *x*" when partial differentiating wrt *y*, and *f* '(*xy*).*y* when partial differentiating wrt *x*?

Cause I don't get it why differentiating *f* with *x* and *y* would both yield *f* ', any help?

Comment: Careful: if this is a function of two variables you need the product rule - and saying $f'$ here makes no sense

Comment: @SeanRoberson Exactly! I know right, I just saw it in my book, where it was mentioning how to form Partial Differential Equations, by eliminating arbitrary functions!

Comment: As you have written it, $f$ appears to be a function of a single variable, say $t \mapsto f(t)$, which you are evaluating at $t=xy$.  This is a composition of functions, hence chain rule applies.  So, for example, $$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} f(xy) = f'(xy) \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{dx}}(xy) = f'(xy) y. $$

Comment: @XanderHenderson I already know that much but $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}y} f(xy) = f'(xy) \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{dy}}(xy) = f'(xy) x$.
Is this _f '_ the same as the one we get when differentiating with _x_?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments, my guess is that the Newton notation is getting in the way a little.  It might be more clear what is going on if we are a little more explicit with the functional composition, and if we use the Leibniz notation instead.

Suppose that
$$ f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$$
is a real-valued function of a single real variable, and let
$$ u : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R} $$
be a real-valued function of two real variables defined by the formula
$$ u = u(x,y) = xy.$$
Then the function $g = f\circ u$ is a real-valued function of two real variables.  The partial derivatives of $g$ can be found via the chain rule:
$$ g_x
= \frac{\mathrm{d}(f\circ u)}{\mathrm{d}x}
= \frac{\mathrm{d}f}{\mathrm{d}u} \cdot \frac{\mathrm{d}u}{\mathrm{d}x}
= \frac{\mathrm{d}f}{\mathrm{d}u} \cdot y,$$
where $\frac{\mathrm{d}f}{\mathrm{d}u}$ is the derivative of the single variable function $f$.  This derivative is not taken with respect to either $x$ or $y$, but instead with respect to the variable of $f$, which we have labeled $u$.  Note that as $f$ is a function of a single variable $u$, it makes sense to write $f'(u)$ instead of $\frac{\mathrm{d}f}{\mathrm{d}u}(u)$.

---

Perhaps an example would help:  suppose that $f(u) = \cos(u)$, and take $u = xy$.  Then
$$ \frac{\mathrm{d}f}{\mathrm{d}x}
= \frac{\mathrm{df}}{\mathrm{d}u} \cdot \frac{\mathrm{d}u}{\mathrm{d}x}. \tag{1}$$
But
$$ \frac{\mathrm{d}f}{\mathrm{d}u} = \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}u} \cos(u)
= -\sin(u). $$
Then, as $u = xy$, it follows that $\frac{\mathrm{d}f}{\mathrm{d}u} = -\sin(xy)$.  Also note that $\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{\mathrm{d}x} = y$.  Substituting these into (1), we conclude that
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}f}{\mathrm{d}x} = -\sin(xy) \cdot y. $$

Comment: Yeah, thank you, that makes sense. I really hate books that don’t lay out a clear notation convention that they’re using.